# How to use Linked Files in Eclipse for PhoneGap project with Android

Tags: android, eclipse

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to link assets/www folder in Eclipse / Phonegap / Android project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6843181/how-to-link-assets-www-folder-in-eclipse-phonegap-android-project)

I want to develop the html and javascript files for my phonegap project in a different folder than the standard "assets/www" folder (for android sdk on eclipse windows).  i thought i could include a linked folder in my eclipse project but the linked folder did not appear to compile into the apk as the app stated that the resource could not be found.
anyone else try to do this?

Comment: Are you getting exception (from Trace) "java.io.FileNotFoundException?  Assets are automatically compressed as part of putting them in the APK file so you may not b seeing it. I do use HTML files in sub folders w/in the assets/www folder w/o an issue. I believe because the HTML files are compressed, Android needs to know that they are HTML & does so by having the files in that folder only.

Comment: Isn't this what you are looking for?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6843181/how-to-link-assets-www-folder-in-eclipse-phonegap-android-project

Answer (score 3):

I use symlinks, yes they work on windows also.
I have tested it with phonegap in visual studio/windows phone project and it works fine.

See wikipedia for details http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_symbolic_link

Example: (Make sure you have moved your www folder to c:\www )

```
cd MyProject/assets/

mklink /D www c:\www
```

That should do it